# Cordova camera not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

We've tried to open the camera from android device using phonegap but not able to do that. Can you please help us with that.

Below is the code written.

```
<div>
        <input class="camerabutton" id="btnCamera" value="open camera" type="button" height="100" width="100" />
       </div>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova_plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = new Framework7();

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

$$('.camerabutton').on('click', function () {

      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 50
            });


        function onSuccess(imageData) {
          alert("test");
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
});
  </script>
```

Config.xml file(Given all the permissions)

```
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Let us know if any issue in mentioned code above or need to add something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh, after doing some research we can able to fix that issue. It was the issue in config.xml so I replaced that with the code mentioned below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>test</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="Contacts.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <feature name="Contacts">
   <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
</feature>
<feature name="Camera">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: It would be useful to others if you were more specific about which lines you changed

Comment: Can you please ellaborate your answer? Because my config have CameraLauncher. But still not luck. 

Firstly, I am checking permission using checkPermission, then if not then request permission, after user allowing calling getPicture. But getting ** " {"__zone_symbol_currentTask": {"type":"microTask", "state":"notScheduled", "source":"Promise.then", "zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount"0}}
 **

Comment: Works smart dude! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding to your options next to quality:

```
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

The default of File_uri wasn't working for me until I changed it.

Also my cordova camera plugin died somehow once.  Uninstalling the plugin and reinstalling it instantly fixed my camera issues.

Comment: I tried all the things that you've mentioned above but still it's not working.

Comment: I just ran into an issue where the camera imageData was not being saved because I didn't have the line allowEdit: true in the camera options same place as above.  With allowEdit: false or nothing there the camera broke completely.

Comment: Thanks for help but my issue is still persists. I don't want any imagedata, I just want to open a camera and that's not opening.